# Выделение адресной строки браузера

Tags: javascript

Задумка очень простая но не могу ее реализовать, при клике в определенной области сайта выделялась адресная строка браузера, для учебного копирования ссылки. Возможно ли это реализовать на  js
Уже который день читаю учебники по javascript может вы сможете мне помочь.

Comment: Наверное будет проще сразу адрес текущей страницы в буфер обмена отправить, чем строку выделять.

Comment: Я с вами согласен так он конечно, упрощает задачу, но хотелось бы добиться выделения адресной строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, то `javascript` не имеет доступа к браузеру => выделить строку никак не получится.

Правильный ответ вам подсказали в комментарии - просто копируйте текущий `URL` в буфер обмена.

Comment: Спасибо, что уделили мне время.